# Is it possible to mix different APIs that are based on a single library ?

Tags: android, routes, offline, android-library, osmdroid

I want to develop an app that works with offline maps, and I need to be able to :

- Geocode
- Route between two coordinates
- Calculate distance between two coordinates
- Search places with autocomplete

So these are pretty difficult tasks since they all must work offline. I have found many Apis, like MapsMe, or MapsForge, all saying that they are based on the osm library. So does this mean that I should be able to "mix" these apis and make them work on a single map ?
For example: use the nice map of MapsMe and the routing system of MapsForge on the same map

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible.

That said, they all may use the same `source` data (open street maps) but osmdroid and mapsforge pre-process them differently. Osmdroid normally only `displays` prerendered tiles either via a server or using mapsforge. Osm Bonus Pack adds routing using online sources (and only online sources).

Mapsforge preprocesses the osm data into an intermediate database format. Tiles are then rendered on device, on demand. POI info, as far as I've been able to determine, requires another separate database. The last I checked, they didn't have any routing capability but were working on getting POI information into their intermediate database format. Best place for info related to this is the mapsforge github site.

Calculating the straight line distance between two points is trivial and doesn't require any map engine. It's just math. Distance along a route is also straight map, so long as you have the set of points. Don't forget the factor in the earths curvature.

Geocoding, converting a lat/lon to an approximate or exact address and going back again can be done with the osm data, but I'm not aware of anything can do this offline, for the entire planet.

You'll also have to take consideration for the geographic area. osm data is huge, around 40gb for the planet, compressed. Obviously, you'll need to subset the data somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Just a few precisions : I need an offline maps for a really small area, actually only for Paris (for now),  and when you say " so long as you have the set of points", do you mean that I can get all the points that separate by routes two coordinates, offline ? So would that mean that I could draw vectors between every points and make my own routing system ?